# RegEx to validate and format bond number

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the following String pattern in which input should be formated as below.

```
01-XXX-000001-01-0001 or 01-XXX-000001-01-001
```

desc of input.

```
01: any two digit Number
xxx: any three characters 
000001: Any 6 digit number
01: Any two digit number
0001: any number up to 4 digits
```

user can input normal string without hyphen or with hyphen

**Case 1 :** if user enter 01XXX000001010001 **then**  result should be 01-XXX-000001-01-0001

**Case 2 :** if user input 01-XXX-000001-01-0001 then no change required.

regex will be more help full for me.

I have tried this below but it works only for numbers.

```
var n = "345453353435443435";
document.write(n.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{3})(\d{6})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3-$4-$5"));
```

Comment: This doesn't look like a job for regex. Regex can't insert into strings, it only matches what is already there, you might be better doing this using javascript code rather than a regex pattern.

Comment: If you already know the pattern you can use e.g. slice and create the required string. The regex to check for either string should be pretty simple too like 0|1-?X{3}-?0{5}1-?01-?0{3}1

Comment: use this pattern: `/([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})([a-zA-Z0-9]{6})([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})([a-zA-Z0-9]{4})/`

Comment: @hadi When I type "43-XPR-000643-01-0001" it returned false. can you Please tell me complete jquery Code to do so.

Comment: @hadi Your regular expression is too permissive and it's not working when the user enters the dashes between the capture groups.

Comment: ok, use this instead: /([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})-?([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})-?([a-zA-Z0-9]{6})-?([a-zA-Z0-9‌​]{3})-?([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}‌​)/

Comment: Still too permissive. Capture groups 1, 3, 4 and 5 are supposed to carry numbers only. The last group is supposed to allow a number between 1 and 4 digits. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```js
const regex = /^(\d{2})-?([a-zA-Z]{3})-?(\d{6})-?(\d{2})-?(\d{1,4})$/;
const reformat = str =>
  regex.test(str) ? str.replace(regex, '$1-$2-$3-$4-$5') : null;
```

#### Tests

```
const assert = require('assert');
assert.equal(reformat('invalid-format'), null);
assert.equal(reformat('01-XXX-000001-01-0001'), '01-XXX-000001-01-0001');
assert.equal(reformat('01XXX000001010001'), '01-XXX-000001-01-0001');
assert.equal(reformat('01XXX000001011'), '01-XXX-000001-01-1');
assert.equal(reformat('43-XPR-000643-01-0001'), '43-XPR-000643-01-0001');
assert.equal(reformat('43XPR000643010001'), '43-XPR-000643-01-0001');
```